# How to switch Xamarin forms Main Page from Master Details Page to Content Page?

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, navigation, cross-platform, logout

I am working on an Xamarin forms Application. In which on App.cs I check

```
CrossSecureStorage.Current.HasKey("SessionToken")
```

then navigate to HomePage() which is a Masterdetailspage and if no security token then I navigate to LoginPage() which is a ContentPage like this

```
if (CrossSecureStorage.Current.HasKey("SessionToken"))
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage(true));
else
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(this));
```

then when user clicked login button I set main page to HomePage() like this

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage(true));
```

and when user clicked logout button I set main page to login again like this

```
CrossSecureStorage.Current.DeleteKey("SessionToken");
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(this));
```

It works fine when user is already logged out. Login and logout both works fine. But if user was already logged in says

```
CrossSecureStorage.Current.HasKey("SessionToken")
```

has value then on logout button press app crashes and got this Exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid.Parameter name: instance
```

I figure out that if in App.cs I changed HomePage from MasterDetailsPage to a new ContentPage then on button press change MainPage to HomePage then it works fine but I want to directly show homepage to user. (Means if first page assigned to MainPage is a ContentPage then app works fine but if first page is a MasterDetailsPage then app crashes on reassigning MainPage to any Page.)
Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: don't add MasterDetail page to navigation page. This is not recommended design with unexpected result. Set your main page to masterdetals page without adding masterdelais page to navigation page